# Why can my NSPredicate filter for one entity attribute but not the other?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swift3, nspredicate

I want to use an `NSPredicate` to display school subjects stored in Core Data that have their start date set to a specific month. I currently store the month names as strings. The problem is that the debugger prints out "Number of results: 0" when I try to display subjects filtered by "startMonth" (I try with August in this example, which should return English but doesn't!).

However, and this is the weird part, if I filter by the name "English" I get 1 result (i.e. English. I also print out its "startMonth" in the loop afterwards and the startMonth is indeed "August"). Does anyone know why everything works out fine when I search for names but not for months? Of course I've double checked that the month is correctly capitalized, that I didn't confuse startMonth and endMonth, etc... I just can't figure out why I can filter for one attribute but not for the other...

So, this isn't working, the debugger prints out "Number of results: 0" (should return 1 result):

```
func getSubjects() {

    let delegate = AppDelegate()
    let monthPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", "startMonth", "August")
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Subject> = Subject.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = monthPredicate

    do {
        let searchResults = try delegate.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        print("Num of results: \(searchResults.count)")
        for subject in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {
            print(subject.value(forKey: "name")!)
            print(subject.value(forKey: "startMonth")!)
            print(subject.value(forKey: "endMonth")!)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error in request")
    }

}
```

This is working, however:

```
func getSubjects() {

    let delegate = AppDelegate()
    //Only this line has changed:
    let monthPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", "name", "English")
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Subject> = Subject.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = monthPredicate

    do {
        let searchResults = try delegate.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        print("Num of results: \(searchResults.count)")
        for subject in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {
            print(subject.value(forKey: "name")!)
            print(subject.value(forKey: "startMonth")!)
            print(subject.value(forKey: "endMonth")!)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with request")
    }

}
```

Now the debugger prints:

```
"Num of results: 1
English
August
December"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try once `NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[c] %@", "startMonth", "August")`

Comment: wow, it worked.. so it was that simple... But do you know why the "%K = %@" version worked for name but not for startMonth? What makes startMonth different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have entered the value with `startMonth` may be it has also included extra `leading or trailing space` with it.

You can resolve this issue using two ways.

1. When you entering value trim the extra space.
2. Use `CONTAINS` with `predicate` instead of `=` it will check that string is contains given string or not.